When_validate_item and When_validate_record tigger did not fire when record move to next record
sir
i create simple master detail form in oracle form 6i and show the employee address from other table by query using when_walidate_item and when_validate_rocord triggers but both did not work and not fire when i move the mater record the detail block when_walidate_item  triggers did not fire
see my simple code
if :employees.employee_id is not null then
select empaddress into :employees.TEXT_ITEM4 from addresstale where empadd_ID := :employees.empadd_id;
end if;

if :employees.employee_id is not null then
select empaddress into :employees.TEXT_ITEM4 from addresstale where empadd_ID := :employees.empadd_id;
end if;


Similarly to your previous question, create POST-QUERY block-level trigger which uses the same code.
Pay attention to correct syntax; in where clause, use =, not :=.
Also, presuming that employee_id is a primary key item/column, it should always contain value and can't be null. If that's so, you don't need to check it (i.e. remove if :employees.employee_id is not null then ... end if;
Code you need, in that case, is just
select empaddress 
into :employees.TEXT_ITEM4 
from addresstale 
where empadd_ID = :employees.empadd_id;

